# Macros not showing up on list in excel ribbon

Tags: excel, vba, add-in, locked

i made add-in for excel, i locked it with password. Now when i try to add button to ribbon, macros are not shown on macros list. When i enter password in vba editor to unlock the project macros are availible on macros list. Does someone know how to let users install add-in and add button to ribbon with asigned macro then project is locked?

Subs are parameterless

Comment: `Public Sub MySub()`?

Comment: Thanks, but subs are public